# How to skip a scenario in Lettuce?

Tags: python, django, lettuce

I'm using Lettuce to do BDD testing on my Django website.  I'm also using CircleCI do some continuous integration.  I have a scenario that fails on CircleCI *every* time, so I'd like to tell CircleCI to skip it.  Something like:

```
@skip_circle
Scenario: My Scenario blah blah
    Give I am skipping some scenarios
    .
    .
    .
```

Is this possible with Lettuce?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to find out that this feature is already implemented, just not documented.  And the decorators are actually called "Tags".

```
@skip_circle
Scenario: My scenario that does stuff
    Given I do stuff
    .
    .
```

Then run:

```
lettuce --tag=-skip_circle
./manage.py harvest --tag=-skip_circle #for django
```

If you leave out the minus sign, you'll only run tests with that tag.  The minus sign tells lettuce to skip the tag.

Comment: Do take note that the following will work `lettuce -t -skip_circle` but `lettuce -t -@skip_circle` will not work